# Application Version and Build number not updating in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, version, swift5

I am currently trying to display the number version of my application I want to show it in a 3 digit format (1.0.0 for example) this is the code i am using to get my application version:

```
func version() -> String {
        let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
        let version = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
        let build = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
        return "\(version) build \(build)"
    }
```

the problem I have is even when i change the **Version number** and the **Build number** in the general information of my app it always displays the same values:

1.0 and build 10

Am I doing something wrong or I am not doing something correctly to update the version number?

Comment: You are force-casting an optional variable three times?  GGGGG...

Comment: That code works. I am using similar code in my app, and just replaced my code with yours and everything displays correctly. Version and Build. It sounds like you're setting your app version correctly, so perhaps check your plist file and make sure nothing got manually changed there.

Comment: thank you dan, the value was being set in the info plist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was inside the infoplist file, the value was being set to 1.0